# Java making arrays of doubles while reading from another file

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to make a program which has a main class which reads the input file and call an other class to store the doubles the file contains..And the other class I am calling puts the double in two arrays but I am not succeeding in it.Any help would be highly appreciated.
This is the main class:

```
package Assignments;

import java.util.Scanner;

import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

public class Processing {

Processing(){
    UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput();   
}

private void start() {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfClusters=in.nextInt();
    int numberOfElements=in.nextInt();
    int numberOfVariables=in.nextInt();

    String line=in.nextLine();
    String lineToIgnore=in.nextLine();
    NumberRow i=new NumberRow(numberOfElements);

    while(in.hasNext()){
        String lineToFindDouble=in.next();
        NumberRow.start(lineToFindDouble);  
    }
    System.out.println("\nend");


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Processing().start();
}

}
```

and the class I am calling to store the doubles is:
    package Assignments;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

public class NumberRow {
static int i;
static double[] fatContent;
static double[] protienContent;

NumberRow(int numberOfElements){
    this.i=numberOfElements;
    fatContent=new double[i];
    protienContent=new double[i];
}

static void start(String in){

    Scanner findingDoubles=new Scanner(in);

    int counter=0;
    while(findingDoubles.hasNext()){
    double fat=findingDoubles.nextDouble();
    double protien=findingDoubles.nextDouble();
    fatContent[counter]=fat;
    protienContent[counter]=protien;
    counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fatContent));
}
}
```

the input file i am using is:

```
7
25
2
Mammal  fat_content(%)  protein_content(%)
Bison   7.9 5.9
Guinea_pig  3.9 8.1
Dolphin 14.0    10.4
Donkey  1.4 1.7
Goat    4.1 3.4
Deer    19.7    9.2
Dog 8.3 9.5
Yak 6.7 5.3
Camel   3.4 3.5
Cat 10.9    11.1
Rabbit  13.1    7.1
Llama   3.2 3.9
Human   43.9    7.4
Mule    1.8 2.0
Elephant    5.0 4.0
Horse   1.3 2.1
Rat 12.6    12.3
Reindeer    20.3    10.4
Sheep   6.4 5.6
Pig 5.1 6.6
Fox 5.9 7.4
Whale   42.3    10.9
Polar_bear  31.0    10.2
Zebra   4.8 3.0
Seal    53.2    11.2
```

the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
at Assignments.NumberRow.start(NumberRow.java:25)
at Assignments.Processing.start(Processing.java:25)
at Assignments.Processing.main(Processing.java:33)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS:I am beginner so I apologise if my code looks stupid to you.

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot figure it out by yourself after all the answers below. I am prepared to help I'll even help you to write the code line by line if that's needed :).

Comment: @Roan Thanks a lot for being so nice....I have figured it out but I highly appreciate your offer to help.....Thanks :)

Comment: No problem good too see you figured it out and good luck with the rest of you code :)

Comment: No problem that's the beaty of this site people helping each other and offering help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Mistake

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    String lineToFindDouble=in.next();
    NumberRow.start(lineToFindDouble);  
}
```

You will get `Bison` when you perform `next()` at this position . 
You should change this code as

```
 while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String lineToFindDouble=in.nextLine();
        NumberRow.start(lineToFindDouble);  
    }
```

So you will be passing to `NumberRow.start("Bison   7.9 5.9")`

Next

In your numberRow

```
 while(findingDoubles.hasNext())
```

At this moment the scanner cursor points to `Bison` .
You should change to

```
while(findingDoubles.hasNextDouble())
```

So that scanner will continue to find double and wait at next first double .

when you call next() Scanner stops if its find space / double / int or so check documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Within the while at the `start` method you should use [hasNextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29) instead just `hasNext` at its loop condition.

You need to check if there are more than 2 doubles per line too. Something like:

```
static int i;
static double[] fatContent;
static double[] protienContent;
static int counter;

NumberRow(int numberOfElements){
    this.i=numberOfElements;
    fatContent=new double[i];
    protienContent=new double[i];
    counter = 0;
}

static void start(String in){

    Scanner findingDoubles=new Scanner(in);

    while(findingDoubles.hasNext()){
      String name = findingDoubles.next();
      if(!findingDoubles.hasNextDouble()) continue;
      double fat=findingDoubles.nextDouble();
      if(!findingDoubles.hasNextDouble()) continue;
      double protien=findingDoubles.nextDouble();
      fatContent[counter]=fat;
      protienContent[counter]=protien;
      counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fatContent));
```

Besides, as it has been exposed in Adam Yost's answer, `counter` should not be reset at `start` method.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems I can see right away.

You are skipping the Bison row. You call in.nextLine, then linetoignore is ANOTHER in.nextLine.

You are calling .nextDouble, and it wants to return a string.
In your `start` method of `NumberRow` you take a line, and call nextDouble on it. In reality, though, you know the first entry is a string. You could fix it by simply calling `in.next` at the beginning of your start method, to discard the string.

Lastly, you are reseting the counter to 0 everytime you call start, so it is just going to overwrite every time. Set the counter in your constructor, then reference it in start.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.nextDouble() reads and interprets the next value as a double. You're reading strings and attempting to translate them into doubles